# QGIS 2.16 adding certain WFS failed

Tags: wfs, qgis-2.16

After switching from 2.14.1 to 2.16.1 adding layers from a certain WFS results in an error, example is with version 1.0.0 forced:

> Layer is not valid: The layer srsname='EPSG:28992'
>   typename='app:Bouwvlak'
>   url='http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?'
>   version='1.0.0' table="" sql= is not a valid layer and can not be
>   added to the map

QGIS WFS log:

> Analysis of DescribeFeatureType response failed for url 
>   srsname='EPSG:28992' typename='app:Bouwvlak'
>   url='http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?'
>   version='1.0.0' table="" sql=: Cannot find element 'Bouwvlak'

I guess the problem is in parsing the [DescribeFeatureType response](http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak&&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType), but I do find the element 'Bouwvlak':

```
...
<element name="Bouwvlak" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature">
    <complexType>
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="fid" type="integer"/>
                    <element name="bestemmingsvlak" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="historisch" minOccurs="0" type="boolean"/>
                    <element name="identificatie" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="naam" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="plangebied" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="planstatus" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="typePlan" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="versieIMRO" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="verwijzingNaarObjectgerichteTekst" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="geometrie" minOccurs="0" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType"/>
                    <element name="dossierID" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="dossierStatus" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="datum" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                    <element name="verwijzingNaarExternPlan" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</element>
...
```

**What I tried:**

- loading the features with FME - works
- manual [request in browser](http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992&MAXFEATURES=1) - works
- force version to 1.0 / 1.1 / 2.0 in QGIS - no luck
- ignore axis orientation in QGIS - no luck
- Using Wireshark I checked the differences in requests from 2.14.1 and 2.16.1:

***2.14.1 requests:***

GetCapabilities

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0

DescribeFeatureType

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak&&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType

GetFeature (1)

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992&MAXFEATURES=1

GetFeature (all)

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992

GetCapabilities

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992

***2.16.1 request***

GetCapabilities

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&ACCEPTVERSIONS=2.0.0,1.1.0,1.0.0

DescribeFeatureType

http://afnemers.ruimtelijkeplannen.nl/afnemers2012/services?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAME=app:Bouwvlak

No differences up to this step, so now I am stuck. Switching back to 2.14 works but I prefer using 2.16.

Can someone tell me this is a bug or a problem in the service?

Comment: I confirm I get the same error with my QGIS 2.16.0 install on Windows.  I note that if I use the WFS 2.0 client plugin, then I can get the data, so that might be a workaround for you.

Comment: Could you provide your update as answer, so its directly obvious, it has been fixed already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logged this as an issue (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15395) at 05-08-2016. Closed / fixed 09-08-2016 (thats quick) with the comment:

```
Fixed per 4bcbc1e (and backported in master_2 in f17f6ac, and in release-2_16 a0e3e76)
```

I'm not sure how the release cycle works and when the fix will be available but will update.

---

In my current installation this issue is fixed.

```
QGIS version 2.16.2
QGIS code revision 979e1a2
```